# How to loop through array and assign every item a value without loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array of object like so:

```
let data = [{Date : null, id: null}, {Date : null, id: null}, {Date : null, id: null}]
```

And i need to assign every Date property a value.
I did it with a loop

```
let dates = ['2022-01-01','2022-02-02','2020-02-03']
for (let i=0; i<dates.length; i++) {
  data[i].Date = dates[i]
}
```

But i was wondering is it possible to do with one line?
I was trying to use something like this, but it didn't work.

```
 data.map((i)=>{
  data[i].Date = dates[i]
 })
```

Because `i` doenst hold index but a value.
Is it possible to use `i` as index iterator in map ?

Comment: Array#map has a second parameter containing the current index, so you can use as follows: `data.map((date, index) => ({ ...date, Date: dates[index] }))`

Comment: `data.map((i, index) => {...i, Date: dates[index]})`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map but what you *really* want is `forEach`.

Comment: Just for clarification, array methods like `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `filter` iterate an array entirely as well (thus they are looping). But unlike classic `for`  or `while` loops, they are each specialized in applying a custom callback function to every array item for a very specific purpose. Thus, reading such code, one already gets an idea of what is going to happen. And about the OP's wish of ... _"do[ing it] with one line?"_ ... One-liners are mostly overrated and unfortunately all too often not very well readable crap (which of cause is not the case for the OP's specific task).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array, if you want to alter `data`,
use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) so you can get the current index to find the desired value in `dates`

```
data.forEach((d, i) => d.Date = dates[i]);
```

---

```js
let data = [{Date : null, id: null}, {Date : null, id: null}, {Date : null, id: null}];
let dates = ['2022-01-01','2022-02-02','2020-02-03'];

data.forEach((d, i) => d.Date = dates[i]);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more functional, in a cleaner way by using map...

```js
let data = [{Date : null, id: null}, {Date : null, id: null}, {Date : null, id: null}];
let dates = ['2022-01-01','2022-02-02','2020-02-03'];

const newData = data.map((a, i) => ({Date : dates[i], id : a.id}));

console.log(newData);
```